# Angular: check if property is in present in data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to check if some data are present in array of object but unfortunately i'm not able to the following:

Here's my data in my controller:

```
$scope.data = [{
      users:[
        {name: 'Stephen', age: 50, dev: 'js', car: 'red', shoes:'green', happy: 'true', videoGame:{isPlayer: 'true', console:'PS3'}},
        {name: 'Stephen', age: 28, dev: 'angular', car: 'gold', shoes:'silver', happy: 'true', videoGame:{isPlayer: 'false', console:'none'}},
        {name: 'Adam', age: 43, dev: 'php', car: 'blue', shoes:'yellow', happy: 'true', videoGame:{isPlayer: 'true', console:'XBOX'}},
        {name: 'John', age: 27, dev: 'java', car: 'green', shoes:'black', happy: 'true', videoGame:{isPlayer: 'true', console:'PC'}},
        {name: 'Steve', age: 29, dev: 'ruby', car: 'white', shoes:'blue', happy: 'true', videoGame:{isPlayer: 'false', console:'none'}},
        {name: 'Pablo', age: 34, dev: 'java', car: 'pink', shoes:'red', happy: 'false', videoGame:{isPlayer: 'true', console:'GAMEBOY'}}
      ],
      futureUsers:[
        {name: 'Walter', age: 56, dev: 'js', car: 'red', shoes:'green', happy: 'true'},
        {name: 'Jessi', age: 27, dev: 'angular', car: 'gold', shoes:'silver', happy: 'true'},
        {name: 'Arnold', age: 34, dev: 'php', car: 'blue', shoes:'yellow', happy: 'true'},
        {name: 'Bill', age: 67, dev: 'java', car: 'green', shoes:'black', happy: 'true'},
        {name: 'Josh', age: 21, dev: 'ruby', car: 'white', shoes:'blue', happy: 'true'},
        {name: 'Sam', age: 31, dev: 'java', car: 'pink', shoes:'red', happy: 'false'}
      ]
    }];
```

I'm trying to check in **futureUsers** if the property **videoGame** is present. If not, i'm trying to add it for each user in the same way it's present in **users** like this:

```
$scope.checkData = function(dataTocheck){
      angular.forEach(dataTocheck, function(){
        if(!dataTocheck.hasOwnProperty('videoGame')){
          var newProperty = {videoGame:{isPlayer: 'true', console:'none'}};
          $scope.dataTocheck.push(newProperty)
          return $scope.dataTocheck;
        }
      })
    };

    $scope.checkData($scope.data.futureUsers);
```

Here's a link to a plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/G0C2l7Ko9kffnemtJiew?p=preview

Comment: what is the problem/error?

Comment: What it have in common with AngularJS? This is just iteration over array

Comment: The problem is that i don't know if this checkData function is working... probably not because the value of player and console are not displayed in the table and one error i saw is Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: @Krzysztof Safjanowski ,Maybe there is a way to do that in angularjs why down vote this question?

Comment: @tarboosh This is common JavaScript problem, you should first learn JS than AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it. Try it in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kTwLAYeaB67rlXCkcxb3?p=preview).

I've found some errors in your code. Your function **checkData** for updating **futureUsers** is incorrect (you didn't pass object to iterate over it in forEach function and you used **return** after each iteration).

```
$scope.checkData = function(futureUsers){
  angular.forEach(futureUsers, function(futureUser){
    if(!futureUser.hasOwnProperty('videoGame')){
      futureUser.videoGame= {isPlayer: 'true', console:'none'}
    }
  })
};
```

[Check documentation about forEach loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach).

And I think that your **$scope.data** variable must be an object, not array. So ng-repeat directives in your table's tags are unnecessary.

Comment: I was wondering if my data is in fact an array of object is it changing something in the way you fixed it?

Comment: Yes, if you want so. You can change your function $scope.checkData to my version and call it $scope.checkData($scope.data[0].futureUsers); at the end of the controller. Because your $scope.data is an array which contains only one object with users and futureUsers properties.

Comment: So perfect man, if i could,  i upvote one more time your previous answer ;)